# How To Rearrange Data Set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am trying to rearrange my data set which currently looks like this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I have been manually transposing and adding up the values for each source and trying my hand at using Python to automate this task. Would anybody be so kind to help me get started in the right direction?

Comment: Have you considered using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library? This sort of work is right up its alley.

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potential pandas solution.

I made a test csv file. Didn't copy yours verbatim but the structure is there

test_data.csv

```
Source,10/30/2017,10/31/2017,11/1/2017,11/2/2017,11/3/2017,11/4/2017,11/5/2017
A,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
B,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
C,20,21,22,23,24,25,26
A,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
B,30,31,32,33,34,35,36
C,35,36,37,38,39,40,41
```

Here's the python code to process the data as you want it

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')
df = df.set_index('Source')
ser = df.unstack('Source')
ser = ser.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()
ser = ser.sort_index(level=1)
```

At this point, `ser` looks like this

```
            Source
10/30/2017  A         35
10/31/2017  A         37
11/1/2017   A         39
11/2/2017   A         41
11/3/2017   A         43
11/4/2017   A         45
11/5/2017   A         47
10/30/2017  B         45
10/31/2017  B         47
11/1/2017   B         49
11/2/2017   B         51
11/3/2017   B         53
11/4/2017   B         55
11/5/2017   B         57
10/30/2017  C         55
10/31/2017  C         57
11/1/2017   C         59
11/2/2017   C         61
11/3/2017   C         63
11/4/2017   C         65
11/5/2017   C         67
dtype: int64
```

Anything else beyond this would be formatting and saving it to your liking.

Hope this Helps.