# How to rearrange Excel data set with some complex?

Tags: python

I am very new to asking questions to stack overflow. Please let me know if I have missed something.

I am trying to rearrange some data from excel-like below

[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFke5.jpg)

To like:

[Rearranged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49ZrU.jpg)

I already tried one in stack overflow [How to Rearrange Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314740/python-how-to-rearrange-data-set)

I just need to add one more column next to the above answer, but couldn't find an answer with my short python knowledge.

Anyone could suggest a way to rearrange a little more complex than the above link?

Comment: Please include the actual data in your code, not the images.

Comment: Consider including a minimal example of your data and your desired output more clearly. It makes it easier for people to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to transform a little bit your data in order to get to the result you want, but here is my solution:

1.Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

2. Remove the merged title from your data ("Budget and Actual"). You may want to rename you columns as 1/31/2020 Actual and 1/31/2020 Budget. Otherwise, if you have the same column name, Pandas will bring you the columns with a differentiator like '.1'. Sample data below with only a couple of columns for demonstration purposes.

   ```
    Item    1/31/2020   2/29/2020   1/31/2020.1 2/29/2020.1
   0  A     0.01        0.02        0.03        0.04
   1  B     0.20        0.30        0.40        0.50
   2  C     0.33        0.34        0.35        0.36
   ```

3.Create two separate datasets for Actuals and Budget

```
#item name and all budget columns from your dataset 
df_budget = df.iloc[:, 0:12]

# item name and the actuals columns
df_actuals = df.iloc[:, [0,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,22,24,25]]
```

4.Correct the names of the columns to remove the differentiator '.1' and reflect your dates

```
df_actuals.columns = ['Item','1/31/2020','2/29/2020' so far so on...]
```

5.Transform the Date columns in rows

```
df_actuals = df_actuals.melt(id_vars=['Item'], value_vars=['1/31/2020', '2/29/2020'], var_name = 'Date', value_name='Actual')
df_budget = df_budget.melt(id_vars=['Item'], value_vars=['1/31/2020', '2/29/2020'], var_name = 'Date', value_name='Budget')
```

You should see something like this at this point

```
    Item    Date    Actual
 0  A   1/31/2020   0.01
 1  B   1/31/2020   0.20


    Item    Date    Budget
0   A   1/31/2020   0.03
1   B   1/31/2020   0.40
```

6.Merge Both datasets

```
pd.merge(df_actuals, df_budget, on=['Item', 'Date'], sort=True)
```

Result:

```
    Item    Date    Actual  Budget
0   A   1/31/2020   0.01    0.03
1   A   2/29/2020   0.02    0.04
2   B   1/31/2020   0.20    0.40
3   B   2/29/2020   0.30    0.50
4   C   1/31/2020   0.33    0.35
5   C   2/29/2020   0.34    0.36
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!